# Refresh a SwiftUI View on Back Navigation

Tags: swiftui

I have a MainView and DetailView. The MainView displays a list of items. From MainView you can go to DetailView using the push navigation. The DetailView allows to add the item. After adding the new item, I am trying to go back to the MainView and refresh the MainView. It goes back but it never displays the new item unless I restart the app.

I added onAppear on the MainView and I can see it is getting fired. But it still does not update the view.

Here is some code in the MainView:

```
   var body: some View {
        List {
            
            ForEach(movieListVM.movies, id: \.id) { movie in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: AddUpdateMovieScreen(movieId: movie.id),
                    label: {
                        MovieCell(movie: movie)
                    })
            }.onDelete(perform: deleteMovie)
           
            
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .navigationTitle("Movies")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Add Movie") {
            isPresented = true 
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, onDismiss: {
            movieListVM.populateMovies()
        },  content: {
            AddUpdateMovieScreen()
        })
        .onAppear(perform: {
            movieListVM.populateMovies()
        })
        .embedInNavigationView()
```

Here is the code in the ViewModel:

```
class MovieListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var movies = [MovieViewModel]()
    @Published var updated: Bool = false
    
    func deleteMovie(movie: MovieViewModel) {
        let movie = CoreDataManager.shared.getMovieById(id: movie.id)
        if let movie = movie {
            CoreDataManager.shared.deleteMovie(movie)
        }
    }
    
    func populateMovies() {
        
        let movies = CoreDataManager.shared.getAllMovies()
        for movie in movies {
            print(movie.title) // THIS PRINTS THE UPDATE OBJECTS
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.movies = movies.map(MovieViewModel.init) // THIS POPULATES THE movies correctly. 
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the MainView is not updating, even though I am firing the populateMovies function of the MovieListViewModel.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct AddUpdateMovieScreen: View {
    
    @StateObject private var addMovieVM = AddUpdateMovieViewModel()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State private var movieVS = MovieViewState()
    
    var movieId: NSManagedObjectID?
    
    private func saveOrUpdate() {
        
        do {
            
 

           if movieId != nil {
// UPDATE IS THE ISSUE I AM TRYING TO RESOLVE 
                    try addMovieVM.update(movieVS)
                } else {
                    addMovieVM.save(movieVS)
                }
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
       
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Enter name", text: $movieVS.title)
            TextField("Enter director", text: $movieVS.director)
            HStack {
                Text("Rating")
                Spacer()
                RatingView(rating: $movieVS.rating)
            }
            DatePicker("Release Date", selection: $movieVS.releaseDate)
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Save") {
                    saveOrUpdate()
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            // if the movieId is not nil then fetch the movie information
            if let movieId = movieId {
                // fetch the movie
                
                do {
                    let movieVM = try addMovieVM.getMovieById(movieId: movieId)
                    movieVS = MovieViewState.fromMovieViewModel(vm: movieVM)
                    
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
        })
        .navigationTitle("Add Movie")
        .embedInNavigationView()
    }
}

struct AddMovieScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddUpdateMovieScreen()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't like FetchRequest because it puts the Core Data queries right inside the View. This makes the app tighly coupled with the View.

Comment: I checked and I can see that the populateMovies is firing and giving me all the new updated movies but I just can't seem to find a way to display them on the UI. The UI is not refreshing to use the new movies.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Added some more code.

Comment: @loremipsum I am using StateObject

Comment: Nothing wrong with the loop. It simply passes the model objects to the view models and construct view model objects and returns an array of view model objects.

Comment: Added another screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show your code for "AddUpdateMovieScreen", here are my guesses:

if you are passing "movieListVM" to "AddUpdateMovieScreen" as ObservableObject, then use this:

```
   .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
        AddUpdateMovieScreen(movieListVM: movieListVM)
    }
```

and:

```
 struct AddUpdateMovieScreen: View {
    @ObservedObject var movieListVM: MovieListViewModel
    ...
```

if you are passing "movieListVM" to "AddUpdateMovieScreen" as EnvironmentObject, then use this:

```
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
        AddUpdateMovieScreen().environment(movieListVM)
    }
```

and:

```
 struct AddUpdateMovieScreen: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var movieListVM: MovieListViewModel 
    ...
```

There is no need for "movieListVM.populateMovies()" in the sheet onDismiss.

Comment: Let me try to create a simpler project for this scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot come up with simple example. Because I have to use Core Data. The sheet is not the issue since I am not performing modal navigation. The navigation is push navigation and the problem is that the details screen adds a new item but when I go back to the main view the new item is not shown on the screen.

Comment: show the relevant code (as text not a picture) in "AddUpdateMovieScreen" so we can see what you do in this view to add the new item.

Comment: AddUpdateMovieScreen has been added as code text. Check out saveOrUpdate function and my bug is related to update. From the MainScreen I go to AddUpdateMovieScreen using push navigation, not sheet(modal) navigation.

Comment: At the moment you declare a "AddUpdateMovieViewModel" inside "AddUpdateMovieScreen".
You don't show the code for "AddUpdateMovieViewModel", did you mean "MovieListViewModel"?
In any case changes to that model do not percolate up to your MainView, 
because there is no `@StateObject var movieListVM = MovieListViewModel()` in your MainView.